# How do you extract mulitiple string values from a function containing arraylists

Tags: java, webdriver

`I wonder if anyone can help me with this problem or advise of a different way to go about it. I am using selenium webdriver, coding with java using testNG framework.

Basically, I have a method that extracts data from excel and stores them as arraylists. So for example, i have

this sort of data:

```
Region      Text1   Text2   Text3
UK          uk_t1   uk_t2   uk_t3
usa         usa_t1  usa_t2  usa_t3
russ        rus_t1  rus_t2  rus_t3
```

My method extracts all the information from excel and stores it into arraylist based on the column name

Example-

```
Arraylist<String>region = new ArrayList<String> ();
Arraylist<String>text1 = new ArrayList<String> ();
Arraylist<String>text2 = new ArrayList<String> ();
Arraylist<String>text3 = new ArrayList<String> ();


ArrayList<String> mydatacells = dataFromExcel(xlspath) // the method on the right is the one with the excel function

String xlspath = "example/mylocation";


int uk = 4; //location of the cell that contains the string uk
int usa   = 8; //location of the cell that contains the string usa
int russ = 12; //location of the cell that contains the string russ
```

I then write the following to extract data specifically for a region

```
for(uk=4; uk<usa; uk++){

region.add(mydatacells.get(uk));
text1.add(mydatacells.get(uk));
text2.add(mydatacells.get(uk));
text3.add(mydatacells.get(uk));

} //the code assigns the value for uk
```

My problem now is that i need to use those values in another method and i need to get all the data.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done or a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to have the data in a map - I assume, the values of the first column are unique and can be used as a key (index). Then I'd write a class to hold the values from a single row:

```
public class Location {
  public String region;
  public String text1;
  public String text2;
  public String text3;
}
```

Now, I'd

1. Read a row from the excel sheet
2. create an instance of Location
3. put that instance to the map, key: location.region, value: location

Comment: Thanks. i'll give that a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Map map = dataFromExcel(xlsPath)